# StreamSets Build Failure on project streamsets-datacollector-dist: Unable to find artifact

Tags: streamsets

I'm trying to build StreamSets Data Collector with source codes by following the steps in public Streamsets git repository ([SDC Public github link](https://github.com/streamsets/datacollector/blob/master/BUILD.md)).

Following picture is the screenshot of error.
[image]
Error message I've got when I tried to build StreamSets with source code

I've done the whole tasks that I should do before building SDC which is written on github build.md page, and following softwares are installed successfully with correct version.

JDK : v1.8
Git : v2.18.0
Maven : v3.5.4
Docker : v18.03.1.ce
Node : v0.10.32
grunt-cli : installed(v1.4.0)
bower : v1.8.2
go : v1.9.2 (gvm used)
gradle : v4.2

I've got the same error message about more than two weeks, and it drives me really crazy. I need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [instructions for building Data Collector Edge in BUILD.md](https://github.com/streamsets/datacollector/blob/master/BUILD.md#prerequisite-tasks-for-building-data-collector) are incorrect. The correct command to build Edge and populate the local Maven repository with the artifacts is:

```
./gradlew clean dist publishToMavenLocal
```

I've opened [SDC-9842](https://issues.streamsets.com/browse/SDC-9842) to fix this. It should be updated on GitHub soon.